# Hessian of element of symmetric square root

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

This is related to a previous question I had.  I'm trying to find the Hessian or second differential for an element of a symmetric square root matrix (found by SVD or spectral decomposition).  So, if S is the symmetric square root of a symmetric positive definite matrix, say, A, such that SS=A, I'm trying to find the Hessian of an element of S, $s_{ij}$, w/r/t vec(A).

I already know how to find the first differential or gradient for vec(S).  For some context, I'm trying to find a Hessian of a complicated composition of functions, and this is one of the intermediate parts.  The function is a scalar-valued function of a vector of parameters, but the issue above occurs while taking differentials.